# where can I found app:checkDebugManifest ?I'm trying to integrate zoom into my flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies, zoom-sdk

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:checkDebugManifest' (type 'CheckManifest').
  - In plugin 'com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidBasePlugin' type 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckManifest' property 'manifest' has @Input annotation used on property of type 'File'.

    Reason: A property of type 'File' annotated with @Input cannot determine how to interpret the file.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Annotate with @InputFile for regular files.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 8s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             10.0s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just open your manifest file and check on the bottom side

[image: Manifest Image]

Comment: Hi, I tried this .But ,could to progress ahead. Still the same error.
may I know some other possible way or sample code to integrate zoom_sdk into flutter app